# How is a $K(\pi_n(X), n)$ called?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, terminology, homotopy-theory

Is there a well-established name for a topological space $X$ whose homotopy groups vanish except for its $n$-th one? In other words, this would be a $K(\pi_n(X), n)$. I am looking for an expression like "Eilenberg-MacLane space of type $(A, n)$" avoiding the mention of a group $A$, but I don't want to invent one.

Comment: I don't know of any established terminology for this, but I'd probably invent the terminology $n$-Eilenberg-MacLane space, perhaps even abbreviated to $n$-EM space or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way would be "Eilenberg-MacLane space of connectivity $n-1$".

I guess this could be criticised as "inventing one" but it is factually correct so it is safe either way.

Comment: Legitimate, but a very uncomfortable "index" switch. I'll wait.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, but you could also say $n$-truncated and $n-1$-connected space. If you want to avoid the index switch, you can also say $n$-connective instead of $n-1$-connected.